# Steghide Linux Steganography how to get "Passphrase"

Tags: linux

I am currently on **Parrot Linux** and have an image has a hidden steganographic inside.

I know I need to decode it with **Steghide** in the Parrot Terminal.

I also know that I will find out what the hidden steganographic data (that with be extracted to a .txt file) with this command:

`steghide extract -sf IMAGE.jpg -p PASSPHRASE`

**The question is, using a command that steghide provides... how would I get the PASSPHRASE to find the hidden message within the image jpg?**

Oh also, I know the seed is `Found (possible) seed: "b40d0b29"` - now I am not sure what that means and if that can assist me in anyway, but I thought I'd drop that here just in case.

Thanks all!